# Wordpress - marge – post type + custom post type + custom column in posts list

Tags: post, types, posts, customcolumn

I have created one custom post type with taxonomy and it works fine.

I am going to show custom post type content in default posts list with help of “pre_get_posts” hooks and it displayed in posts list.

I need to show custom column name as “post type” in default posts list and that will show content post type.
So I have to tried with “manage_posts_custom_column” hooks but here I am not getting custom post type content value “post->ID” and due to this custom post type value are blank for “post type” column.

How to marge custom post type in default posts list with custom column? custom column have their post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have done these using metabox dropdown
and all post type + custom post type data re-entered into default post
and metabox dropdown value which are associated with post show in custom column list. 
So my list post list filter works with that custom column.

Thanks